# Not able to install pandas using pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

While installing `pandas` using pip, I'm getting error. Can someone please help me out with fixing this issue. I'm using python 3.4 on windows10.

```
set build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\pandas/_version.py to '0.22.0'
    running build_ext
    building 'pandas._libs.hashing' extension
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\sthakur1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-2lweg8a9\pandas\setup.py", line 743, in <module>
        **setuptools_kwargs)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 539, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 126, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "C:\Users\sthakur1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-2lweg8a9\pandas\setup.py", line 385, in build_extensions
        build_ext.build_extensions(self)
      File "C:\Users\sthakur1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-2lweg8a9\pandas\setup.py", line 161, in build_extensions
        _build_ext.build_extensions(self)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 503, in build_extension
        depends=ext.depends)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 460, in compile
        self.initialize()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 371, in initialize
        vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc9_support.py", line 52, in query_vcvarsall
        return unpatched['query_vcvarsall'](version, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 287, in query_vcvarsall
        raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
    ValueError: ['path']

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Python34\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\sthakur1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-2lweg8a9\\pandas\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\sthakur1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-todgu5lt-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\sthakur1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-2lweg8a9\pandas\
```

Comment: Please submit the actual lines you entered and format the code properly (using four spaces, as recommended by Stack here https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Check that `pip` is in your `PATH` environment. If it is, just type `pip install pandas`in your terminal. If it's not just look up how to add it. Is there a reason you are using Python3.4 ?

Comment: I am trying to install using : pip install pandas

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried running your CMD window as an administrator?
And try this instead:

```
python -m pip install pandas
```

Also make sure that your python installation folder is in your 'PATH' Environment Variable

Answer (score 2):

This turned out to be a common issue while instaling pandas with pip on python 3.4. That's actually a known bug confirmed by pandas package developers on
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20775

The simplest solution should be:

```
pip install 'pandas<0.21'
```

Answer (score 1):

i believe it has to do with version of PIP the way to fix it is to install pip version 19.3.1 
python -m pip install pip==19.3.1
then you can upgrade to latest pip if needed and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to install Anaconda3 in your system. As it is a Big Python (with a great support of libraries for Data science and many more).

> I love **pandas** and I found **Anaconda** a great tool to work. **Jupyter notebook** is also a great tool to learn, try and enjoy working with Data science. I have worked with 1/2 clients who (had PHD in mathematics or an employee in any organization) suggested me to choose **Anaconda** and **Jupyter notebook**.

- Please uninstall Python 3 from your System. Also remove related paths from **PATH** environment variable.
- Visit https://www.anaconda.com/download/#windows and download **Python 3.7**.
- Install it, do not check (✔) if the installation wizard asks for setting environment variables (it causes issues later).
- Also make a note of **Anaconda's** installation directory basically it would be `C:\Users\sthakur1\Anaconda3` in your case, let's take it as an example.
- Just click **next** by accepting the defaults. At the end of installation, it will ask you to install **VScode**, please install that, just click on **install VSCode** and installer will do the installation.
- Once done,  click on **close/finish** button. Now it's time to add the following paths to **PATH** environment variable one by one.

> The last 2 are optional, you can skip. Actually, that I saw when I check the automatic path settings option the installer also add these 3 as well.
>
> Here https://dev.to/hygull/setting-anaconda-path-on-windows-2dmn is my little article that explains this which can be easily found on Google (Chrome) just by typing `Anaconda path settings` and clicking on 2nd link(mostly), as 1st one takes to Stackoverflow.

```
C:\Users\sthakur1
C:\Users\sthakur1\Library\bin
C:\Users\sthakur1\Scripts
C:\Users\sthakur1\Library\mingw-w64\bin
C:\Users\sthakur1\Library\usr\bin
```

Finally, you can open a new terminal, try the following statements.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"fullname": ["A N",  "P Y"],  "age": [34,  67]}) 
>>> df
```

And now you are done. Please comment if you face any issue.

Comment: My problem is that I use a public cloud to run my app

Answer (score -2):

Use this command to install PANDAS

pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org pandas -vvv

Comment: The issue does not seem related to trusted hosts, it is a Python version issue